# Problem open scp connection from oracle database with java class

Tags: java, database, oracle, connection, scp

We have a java class into oracle database. Our java class opens a scp connection to a remote server to get a file, when the file is readed, the connection is closed in the java class.
We have also one java method of the java class declared as a oracle procedure.
The problem is that sometimes when the java class wants to open de connection, a exception is thrown "java.net.BindException: bind() failed, errno = 98 Address already in use" .
We have ensured that all connections are closed even when an exception is thrown.
Does anyone have any idea of what could be the problem?

Thanks, regards, Angel.